# Select the children of a sibling with a single expression in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to select the children of a sibling of the current context in jQuery using a single expression similar to this?

```
$('~ div > span', this)
```

Unfortunately this does not work for me so I don't believe jQuery supports this type of chaining in an expression. I was however able to get the following methods to work:

```
$('> span', $('~ div', this))


$(this).siblings('div').children('span')
```

I am looking for a way to get the children of a sibling using the following API call, or for an explanation on why it is not possible:

```
jQuery( expression, context )
```

Comment: Why? Is there a real reason why you would need to do something in one step, if it can be done in two? Just curious.

Comment: Purely for educational purposes. Intuitively it seems to me like it should be possible and I was unable to find any documentation that definitively told me one way or the other. So if can have a better understanding of how things work I am hoping that will make my intuition better when using jQuery.

Comment: Do you have some HTML to use as a test case?

Comment: Probably related: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/proper-interpretation-of-unspecified-parent-in-selector-child - jQuery can only do what Sizzle supports, after all.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a bit old but figured I'd answer in case anyone else is trying to do this. [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) is the best way to do this

```
$(this).siblings('div').find('span');
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

you could try `$(this + "+div>span");`

Comment: would you explain this selector?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$(this).next('div').children('span')`

http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/next

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The OP already used a similar approach.